# TemplateBinding in Storyboard | ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames not working

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visualstatemanager, visualstates

I have the following setup. the problem is, that if I switch to the `VisualState` "Alarm", the `AlarmBrush` is not set. I have tried different "Bindings" (see below), but I only get errors like `System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element. BindingExpression:Path=AlarmBrush; DataItem=null; target element is 'DiscreteObjectKeyFrame' (HashCode=39320280); target property is 'Value' (type 'Object')`.

If I replace the value with an ResourceKey, then everything is fine. But I want to have this State dynamic, so a static resource is no opionion.

#### BaseClass

```
[TemplateVisualState(GroupName = "FooGroup", Name = "Alarm")]
public abstract class BaseClass : Control
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty AlarmBrushProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("AlarmBrush", typeof(Brush), typeof(BaseClass), null);
    public Brush AlarmBrush
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(AlarmBrushProperty); }
        set { SetValue(AlarmBrushProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

#### DerivedClass

```
public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public DerivedClass()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(DerivedClass);
    }

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Alarm", true);
    }
}
```

#### XAML Style

```
<Style TargetType="Basic:DerivedClass">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Basic:DerivedClass">
                <Grid>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FooGroup">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Alarm">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background)" Storyboard.TargetName="AlarmBorder">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{Binding AlarmBrush, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Basic:DerivedClass}}, Path=AlarmBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Border x:Name="AlarmBorder" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"  BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                        <TextBlock Text="test" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="5"/>
</Style>
```

#### xaml

```
<Foo:DerivedClass BorderBrush="#FFDA1F1F" AlarmBrush="#FF00FF0C"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going to hate this but I remember this is one of the limitations in WPF. The `Value` property needs to be **frozen** which means you cannot use bindings to dynamically change it. Same thing goes to the `To` property of a `ColorAnimation`.

Since you are not actually *animating* the color (animating a `Brush` will simply change the color instantly), you can always obtain a reference of the `AlarmBorder` and manually set its `Background`.

Comment: Damn.. so it is possible to change the `Background` of the `AlarmBorder` instantly without a storyboard in a `VisualState`? Or do I have to throw away the `VisualStates` and use simple `Properties` in combination with `Triggers` ?

Comment: @DominicJonas Just don't use visual states. Yeah properties with triggers would do.